# Explaining “留守儿童”？

Tags: translation

I'm trying to explain the concept of "留守儿童“ for a school project and am not sure how the translation should go.

> If you don't know, 留守儿童 are the left-behind children of parents who go
>   to cities as workers. Legally, if the parents don't have a home,
>   they're not allowed to bring their children with them, so the children
>   stay in the Chinese countryside alone.

I'm trying to translate the sentence: 留守儿童 are the children left behind of parents who go to cities to work. However, I've tried "留守儿童是父母留工作在市里的孩子" and various online translations: "留守儿童是那些去城市工作的父母留下的孩子", but I'm really not sure which makes sense and is clearest.

Comment: You should check out the baidu baike page https://wapbaike.baidu.com/item/留守儿童/1968574?fr=aladdin I’m sure there are some good sentences you could make use of

Comment: You can pick apart the first sentence: `留守儿童是指外出务工连续三个月以上的农民托留在户籍所在地家乡，由父、母单方或其他亲属监护接受义务教育的适龄儿童少年。` and keep the parts you need/want.

Comment: 美国家长在儿童12岁必须在家陪伴？中国没有这条法律。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option,

> 留守儿童是父母留工作在市里的孩子

Doesn't make sense, because you're saying "the parents left work at the city's children."

As for your second option,

> 留守儿童是那些去城市工作的父母留下的孩子

This works, although it implies the children are left *here.* You could amend the 留下 into 留在乡下 or 留在家里. You can also take out "那些" which sounds a bit too verbose to me.